# how to get the specific data response from controller laravel

Tags: jquery, json

I got confuse regarding getting the specific data value from response json in the controller of laravel. I have here sample which I get the response from controller.

[image: Response]

when i try to get the customer_name the alert result is undefined, why it gives me undefined for that?

I have here my ajax function:

```
$(function(){
            $("button#show_cart").click(function() {
                var fired_button = $(this).val();
                $('#customer_details').val(fired_button);

                var details_id = $('#customer_details').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url:'/customer_data_append',
                    type:'GET',
                    data:{customer_id: details_id},
                    success: function(response) {

                        alert(response.customer_name);


                    },
                     error: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });

            }); 
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

**response** is an array of length 1.

Hence you need to change from:

```
response.customer_name
```

to:

```
response[0].customer_name
```

Comment: yah thanks for that, but i already solved my question thanks @gaetanoM